# ElGamal cryptosystem

Tags: encryption, elgamal-encryption

ElGamal cryptosystem provides multiplicative homomorphic property which can also be converted to additive homomorphic property. Can we use both properties simultaneously? For example, we want to achieve sum and product both simultaneously: E(a_1+a_2,...,a_n) * E(b_1+b_2,...,b_n), for instance, this could be achieved by Paillier but we need number of passes (rounds between both parties) to achieve both addition and multiplication. How about the ElGamal?

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you want to achieve? In particular: 1) In "E(a_1+a_2,...,a_n) * E(b_1+b_2,...,b_n)" what do the "," sign mean (or it + meant instead) ? 2) Are + or/and * modulo something (perhaps $p$ if ElGamal is in group $\mathbb Z_p^*$) ? Is the + operation performed on the plaintext as shown, or is it desired that's the effect of an operation on ciphertext ? 4) If it's desired to compute $a_1*b_1+c_1\bmod p$ by operations on ciphertexts, are some of $a_1$, $b_1$, $c_1$ public or/and constant?

Comment: Nope. Use FHE...

Comment: @fgrieu E(m1)*E(m2)= (g^r1,m1*h^r1)(g^r2,m2*h^r2)=(g^r1+r2,(m1*m2)h^r1+r2)=E(m1*m2) and additive property can be achieved:
E(m1)*E(m2)= (g^r1,g^m1*h^r1)(g^r2,g^{m2} * h^{r2})=(g^r1+r2, g^{m1+m2} * h^{r1+r2})=E(m1+m2).......
We have two encrypted vectors of N encrypted elements:
I want to achieve:
E(v_i+vj)*E(v_i*vj)....
By additive and multiplicative properties:: Can I use both properties simultaneously?? or I can just utilize one..

Comment: OK "," separate vector elements. It remains unclear what "E(a_1+a_2,...,a_n)" exactly stands for (there is no resemblance between the first and last vector components, thus we can't guess what the second component is, or even how many components there are). Independently, distinguish _what_ you want to achieve, from _how_: computing E(v_i+vj)*E(v_i*vj) is trivial (just do it). Is the real goal computing $E(u_1\,v_1+w_1,…,u_N\,v_N+w_N)$ from $E(u_1,…,u_N)$, $E(v_1,…,v_N)$, $E(w_1,…,w_N)$ for $u_i$, $v_i$ _and_ $w_i$ arbitrary secret in some range? No way with ElGamal or Paillier.